# Promises out of order

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

I have a promise nested inside of another promise looking like this:

```
 adb.screencap(list, id).then(function(missing) {
     adb.getScreens(list, id).then(function () {
         res.render('screencap', {output: "Screens captured."})
     })
 })
```

Where adb.screencap and adb.getScreens is:

```
adb.screencap = function(list, id){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var array = new Array();
        var promises = new Array();

        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            var cmd = "adb -s " + list[i] + " shell screencap /sdcard/" + list[i] + "-" + id + ".png";
            var missing = new Array();

            console.log("== " + cmd);
            promises.push(adb.openArray(i, array, list, cmd, missing));
        }
        Promise.all(promises).then(function (missing) {
            console.log(("resolve"));
            resolve(missing);
        })
    })
}
adb.getScreens = function(list, id){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            var cmd = 'adb -s ' + list[i] + ' pull /sdcard/' + list[i] + "-" + id + ".png /home/IdeaProjects/DeviceServer/public/files/" + list[i] + "-" + id + ".png";
            exec(cmd, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
                console.log(stdout);
                console.log(cmd);
            });
        }
        resolve();
    })
}
```

Is there any reason why the adb.getScreens promise is completing before the adb.screencap promise?

Comment: Ah the joy of promises :) I can't offer direct help on this as it hurts my brain but heres a useful link [https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises]

Comment: That's impossible. The callback than contains the call to `adb.getScreens` is only executed *after* `adb.screencap` resolved. Please provide more  (or more precise) information about this issue. What makes you think one promise is completing before the other?

Comment: FWIW, don't create a new promise in `adb.screencap` (`return new Promise(...);`), just `return Promise.all(...)`.

Comment: Well screencap is supposed to capture the screen and then getScreens is supposed to pull the screenshot and send it to a specific folder on my server. From my console output, it shows that it is pulling before it is screen capping. Hence the pull will do nothing because it will not be able to find the file. If I refresh the page, the pull will work because the screencapture would've finished by then.

Comment: What is `adb.openArray`? Does it return a promise?

Comment: Did any of these answers provide an answer your question?  If they did, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the best answer.  That will also earn your some reputation points for following the proper procedure here on stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still trying to figure out what's going wrong, since it seems rather weird this occurs.
It's probably somewhere inside the openArray() method or in the exec() function.

For what it's worth, you can simplify some things, as Felix suggest:

```
// If the getScreens handler doesn't need the 'missing' returned from screencap
adb.screencap(list, id).then(function(missing) {
    return adb.getScreens(list, id);
}).then(function ( gottenScreens ) {
    res.render('screencap', {output: "Screens captured."})
});

// You can just return the Promise.all here instead of adding another promise
// just to resolve the outer one.
adb.screencap = function(list, id) {
    var array = new Array();
    var promises = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        var cmd = "adb -s " + list[i] + " shell screencap /sdcard/" + list[i] + "-" + id + ".png";
        var missing = new Array();

        console.log("== " + cmd);
        // is this some async operation or are you just creating all the commands here?
        // if so, it does't make sense to use a promise here.
        promises.push(adb.openArray(i, array, list, cmd, missing));
    }       
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Comment: Are you referring to this: `promises.push(adb.openArray(i, array, list, cmd, missing));`? Here adb.openArray is a promise and I'm trying to run it for every item inside the list.

Answer (score 1):

You are resolving `getScreens()` before any of the `exec()` calls inside it have completed.  They are async.  They finish sometime later, but you are calling `resolve()` right after you've started them all.  So, you end up trying to render before any of the results you need to render are available.

Instead, you need to promisify `exec()` itself and then collect those promises in an array and use `Promise.all()` to see when all of them are done.  Only then will `getScreens()` actually be done.

There are lots of other issues here too.  `screencap()` is using an anti-pattern.   There's no need to create your own promise here.  You can just return the promise from `Promise.all()` and the use of this anti-pattern causes you to lose any errors thrown by any of the promises.

Here's a recommendation:

```
// promisify exec
function execP(cmd) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        exec(cmd, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            console.log(cmd);
            console.log(stdout);
            console.log(stderr);
            resolve({stdout: stdout, stderr: stderr});
        });
    });
}

adb.getScreens = function(list, id){
    return Promise.all(list.map(function(item) {
       var cmd = 'adb -s ' + item + ' pull /sdcard/' + item + "-" + id + ".png /home/IdeaProjects/DeviceServer/public/files/" + item + "-" + id + ".png";
       return execP(cmd);
    }));
}
```

Now `.getScreens()` returns a promise that will be resolved only when all the `exec()` calls are done (so your output files will be available and ready for your redner).

This configures `.getScreens()` to resolve to an array of objects that contains the stdout, stderr info from all your exec calls.  It doesn't appear you are attempting to use that output anyway, but that's how this is configured.

Answer (score 0):

Does your `adb.openArray` return promise? Then only `Promise.all` will work.

And you should resolve the promise of `getScreens` inside the callback if `exec`. It is outside and does not wait for exec to finish.